# Play video Intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, video

In my App I want that when user clicks a button, an intent should start and shows list of video players in the phone. By choosing one of them a video should start to play. I use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

With this code when I click on the button, MXPlayer started directly and plays video. In the end of video, My App closes entirely! but I want to see a list of players and after end of video back to my App! How can I do this?

EDIT(Whole Code):

```
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


    l_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String file_name="34743773";
            File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AAAAA"+ File.separator +file_name+".mp4");

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)));
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)), "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
 }
```

Comment: it might be a "Default" issue, meaning you might have set "MXPlayer" as your default player, clear that in Apps then try again.

Comment: You might also be seeing this behavior because you specify .mp4 files, which other installed players may not be able to handle. Normally, you provide a URI of "video/*" to show all available players.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: When i put "video/*" it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @KhanZeeshan: MX Player is not my default player. My main problem is that when video end's, Whole App closes!

Comment: @Fcoder Then that begs the question: what other video players are installed? Also, please explain what "Whole App closes!" really means. Normally, when you use an Intent, control passes to the intent target, and you have to use the backstack to get back to your app, so what you're seeing might be normal.

Comment: what happens what you press "back" button while watching the movie and after the movie has ended?

Comment: @MarsAtomic: You know, i want that when video playing end's, Control goes back to my App! but now everything closes and goes to Phone Launcher(Home Screen). Actually, My App Closes within Media Player!

Comment: @KhanZeeshan: While playing video, if i press "back" button, Control goes to Phone Launcher(Home Screen). but i want to back to my App!!

Comment: You need to start posting some code. The behavior is probably entirely unrelated to your use of Intent and has to do with what's in your onPause().

Comment: @MarsAtomic: i don't have any other code in the Activity. It's just a test App. there is nothing in the onPause().

Comment: @Fcoder And then we can safely presume your onResume() is similarly empty? Do you suppose that not having any code in onPause() or onResume() and then effectively pausing and resuming your app is going to present some... difficulties? Finish your app and get back to us.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: there is no any code inside onResume(). i start an intent like starting a new Activity, I expect that when i press "back" in the new Activity, i go back to old one. but right now it doesn't happen. how i can fix it?

Comment: can you post your whole class here, just for our sake

Comment: @KhanZeeshan: i updated my question, You can see whole code.

Comment: everything looks pretty normal, which is scary.

Comment: Have you looked in the logcat? If your app is closing unexpectedly you should find some error messages there. Don't filter the logcat because you might miss something important. You can post the relevant parts of the logcat in your question.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the entire code of the activity. You do `l_video.setOnClickListener(...)` but you don't show us where you declared the variable `l_video` or how it was initialized. Post more code please.